# How to overlap NULL values in MYSQL when using group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

This is my current table, let's call it "TABLE"

[image]

I want end result to be:

[image]

I tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE GROUP BY(service)
```

but it doesn't work

i tried replacing NULL with 0 and then perform group by but "TBA" (text value) is creating problem, kindly help me out!

Comment: Please tag only with the database you are using.   (1) What do you want if more than one column is populated for a service?  (2) I find it doubtful that a table would have this structure.  You probably need to fix the query that generates the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *looks like* simple aggregation:

```
select service, max(for1) for1, max(for2) for2, max(for3) for3
from mytable
group by service
```

This takes advantage of the fact that aggregate functions such as `max()` ignore `null` values. However if a column has more than one non-`null` value for a given `service`, only the greatest will appear in the resultset.

It is unclear what the datatype of your columns is. Different datatypes have different rules for sorting.